# AWS CDK getting DynamoDB Stream ARN returns null

Tags: java, amazon-web-services, aws-cdk, amazon-dynamodb-streams

Is it possible to get the Stream ARN of a DynamoDB table using the AWS CDK?

I tried the below, but when I access the streamArn using the `getTableStreamArn` it returns back null.

```java
ITable table = Table.fromTableArn(this, "existingTable", <<existingTableArn>>);

System.out.println("ITable Stream Arn : " + table.getTableStreamArn());
```

Tried using `fromTableAttribute` as well, but the stream arn is still empty.

```java
 ITable table =
          Table.fromTableAttributes(
              this, "existingTable", TableAttributes.builder().tableArn(<<existingTableArn>>).build());
```

Answer (score 2):

this is not possible with the `fromTableArn` method... Please see the documentation here:

https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cdk/api/latest/docs/aws-dynamodb-readme.html#importing-existing-tables

> If you intend to use the tableStreamArn (including indirectly, for
> example by creating an
> @aws-cdk/aws-lambda-event-source.DynamoEventSource on the imported
> table), you must use the Table.fromTableAttributes method and the
> tableStreamArn property must be populated.

Comment: But even fromTableAttribute did not return the value of the stream arn

Comment: you need to populate it yourself as one of the TableAttributes

Answer (score 1):

That value is most likely not available when your Java Code is running.

With the CDK there is a multi-step process to get your code to execute:

1. Your Java Code is executed and triggers the underlying JSII Layer
2. JSII executes the underlying Javascript/Typescript implementation of the CDK
3. The Typescript Layer produces the CloudFormation Code
4. The CloudFormation Code (and other assets) is sent to the AWS API
5. CloudFormation executes the template and provisions the resources

Some attributes are only available during Step 5) and before that only contain internal references that are eventually put into the CloudFormation template. If I recall correctly, the Table Stream ARN is one of them.

That means if you want that value, you have to create a CloudFormation Output that shows them, which will be populated during the deployment.

Comment: That table is an existing resource in the aws account and was not created as part of the current stack. I'm just trying to access an existing resource's attribute. I see the below comment in aws doc, do you know when it is applicable ?


"If you intend to use the tableStreamArn (including indirectly, for example by creating an @aws-cdk/aws-lambda-event-source.DynamoEventSource on the imported table), you must use the Table.fromTableAttributes method and the tableStreamArn property must be populated."